# ejecutar procedimiento almacenado desde Power BI con parámetros

Tags: sql, powerbi

Es posible ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado con parámetros desde Power BI como normalmente se haría en Excel?

Que ingreses el parámetro en un filtro y cargue la información del sp

es posible? y de ser así, como se hace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que es posible. Cuando defines una nueva importación (Obtener datos --> SQL Server) pones el servidor, la base de datos y presionas sobre Opciones avanzadas, en el cuadro "Instrucción SQL" pones la sentencia sql a ejecutar, en tu caso un exec del procedimiento con sus parámetros.

En mi caso `EXEC MiProcedimiento 1`. Es decir le paso solo un parámetro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo que quieres es que el/los parámetros sean dinámicos, el proceso no es complicado, pero si algo más largo de explicar. Puedes ver [un ejemplo en este enlace](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-user-parameter-in-power-bi/).

Comment: me sirvió el ejemplo que compartiste para que los parámetros sean dinámicos, muchas gracias!